# Convert a floating-point number of seconds to milliseconds using JodaTime / java.time

Tags: java, jodatime

An API I'm calling returns a duration as a fractional number of seconds:

```
double seconds = someOtherApi.getDuration();
```

To convert it to milliseconds we *could* do:

```
long millis = (long) (seconds * 1000);
```

However we use JodaTime in our codebase and would prefer to leave any sort of conversion work up to the library. Unfortunately I don't see an appropriate factory method in JodaTime that takes a `double`.

Is there a "proper" way to convert a fractional duration value into a Joda `Duration`, or is doing so manually the best option?

Comment: Nope, just like that. Jodatime only works with long millis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a converter. Create a class that implements the DurationConverter interface and register it with the ConverterManager.

Here's an example (I tested with JodaTime 2.10):

Converter code:

```
import org.joda.time.convert.DurationConverter;

public class DurationConverterFromDouble implements DurationConverter {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSupportedType() {
        return Double.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getDurationMillis(Object objectDouble) {
        return (int)(((double)objectDouble) * 1000);
    }
}
```

Code:

```
// register the converter
ConverterManager.getInstance().addDurationConverter(new DurationConverterFromDouble());

// create Duration from a double:
double d = 3.14;
Duration jodaDuration = new Duration(d);
System.out.println("Joda duration is " + jodaDuration);
System.out.println("Joda duration in milliseconds is " + jodaDuration.getMillis());
```

Output:

> ```
> Joda duration is PT3.140S
> Joda duration in milliseconds is 3140
> ```

Interestingly, NodaTime (equivalent library for C#) does not require to use a converter to create a Duration directly from a double. I fired up a new C# console project, downloaded NodaTime 2.3.0, played around with the API via intellisense (autocomplete), and found this solution:

Code:

```
double d = 3.14;
var nodaDuration = Duration.FromSeconds(d);
Console.WriteLine("Noda duration is " + nodaDuration);
Console.WriteLine("Noda duration in milliseconds is " + nodaDuration.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Output:

> ```
> Noda duration is 0:00:00:03.14
> Noda duration in milliseconds is 3140
> ```

Comment: So does `Duration` have `getMillis()` method?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Yes it does - I use it in my code in the answer. Did you miss it?

Comment: I've never used Joda time, but if `Duration` gots `getMillis()` method, then what is the need for custom converter, it just return millis!

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh If you read the question carefully, you should notice that the question is not about getting milliseconds from a Duration object but about creating a Duration object from a double, where the double value represents seconds.